# Object.map in JS

Tags: javascript, object, callback

I know that Object in JS doesn't have its own map method.

I would like to create my own map method, that could change key or value of object.

```
const obj = {name:'John', job:'dev'}
```

and it should looks like:

```
const result = obj.map(([key, value], idx, self)=>{
    if(value === 'dev'){
        return { [key]: value }
    }

    return {}
})

  output// result = {job:'dev'}
```

or

```
const result = obj.map(([key, value], idx, self)=>{
    if(key === 'John'){
        return { [key]: value }
    }

    return {}
})

output// result = {name:'John'}
```

Please about an advise!

Comment: If you change `obj.map(` to `map(obj,`, then making the function becomes a lot simpler

Comment: Maybe have a look at `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`, which could help you here.

Comment: Isn't that closer to a `filter` than `map`? I would expect the same number of properties in both input and output otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Object.keys, or very similar.  Here's one way where I get an item {} and an item with {name: "John"}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```js
const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key, idx, self) => obj[key] === 'John' ? {[key]: obj[key]} : {})
```

Another way would be to look into Object.entries. Which is a little less straight forward.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```js
const result2 = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val], idx, self) => val === 'John' ? {[key]: val} : {})
```

Worth noting, the map is ultimately going to return an array. if you are looking for singular thing, then you may want to further reduce/filter this item.